# Program to access cloud service as a mapped drive on Windows XP/7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, cloud-storage

I was wondering if there's an online cloud service that can be accessed as a mapped drive letter on Windows XP and Windows 7? Something that would let me for instance, see files from a cloud in Windows Explorer, then open them as if they were local files and save them the same way.

Comment: Dropbox _sort of_ does what you want, in that it automatically syncs files from a folder (so you can open/save them as you wish). But I'm sure there are better answers that do exactly what you want (no cache).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you do it in Microsoft SkyDrive:

1. Open the folder in the skydrive site using the browser (it would be under Shared menu on the left). The url will look something like: https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=529BD9445B66F60D&id=529BD9445B66F60D%21189#cid=529BD9445B66F60D&id=529BD9445B66F60D%21189. Note the “cid” query parameter in the URL.
2. Right-click on Network (in windows explorer), then “Map Network Drive”
3. Specify Folder as: https://d.docs.live.net/[cid]/[folder_name]. For the sample URL above, it would be https://d.docs.live.net/529bd9445b66f60d/CQRS (note the folder name isn’t in the URL, you need to know it beforehand, and it has to match what it’s named on the site).
4. Check the “Use alternate credentials” option in the dialog.
5. Click Finish. Enter your Live ID credentials when asked.

See for more info: blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/how-to-map-a-shared-skydrive-folder-as-a-network-drive-in-windows/

Answer (score 2):

Here are [instructions](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57426705-285/how-to-map-a-drive-letter-to-google-drive-in-windows/) on how to map Google Drive to a drive letter.

There are other similar programs that work with other cloud storage apps, you just have to Google for them.